# Python: Convert string to datetime, calculate time difference, and select rows with time difference more than 3 days

Tags: pandas, string, datetime

I have a dataframe that contains two string date columns. First I would like to convert the two column into datetime and calculate the time difference. Then I would like to select rows with a time difference of more than 3 days.

simple df

```
ID     Start                End
234    2020-11-16 20:25     2020-11-18 00:10
62     2020-11-02 02:50     2020-11-15 21:56
771    2020-11-17 03:03     2020-11-18 00:10
```

desired df

```
ID     Start                   End                     Time difference
62     2020-11-02 02:50:00     2020-11-15 21:56:00     13 days 19:06:00
```

Current input

```
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(z['End'])
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(z['Start'])
df['Time difference'] = df['End'] - df['Start']
```

How can I select rows that has a time difference of more than 3 days?

Thanks in advance! I appreciate any help on this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your just missing one line, convert to days then query

`df[df['Time difference'].dt.days > 3]`

```
ID     Start                   End                     Time difference
62     2020-11-02 02:50:00     2020-11-15 21:56:00     13 days 19:06:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df=df.set_index('ID').apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))#Set ID as index to allow coercing of dates to datetime
df=df.assign(Timedifference =df['End'].sub(df['Start'])).reset_index()#Calculate time difference and reset index
df[df['Timedifference'].dt.days.gt(3)]#Mask a bollean selection to filter youre desired
```